# Eloquent adds 'is null' to where query after a left join

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Here is my eloquent query:

```
$table =  DB::table('invites')
       ->leftjoin('connections', 'connections.user_id', '=', 'invites.user_id')
       ->where(DB::raw('connections.firm_id = invites.firm_id'))
       ->get();
```

It should return a table of users that are connected to the firm that has invited them.

The query log shows the following query is executed:

```
'query' => 'select * from `invites` left join `connections` on `connections`.`user_id` = `invites`.`user_id` where connections.firm_id = invites.firm_id is null'
```

The `is null` at the end is messing everything up. I assume it's to do with the fact that the column names are the same or am I missing something with DB::raw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**where()** method takes column name as first argument and if next parameters are missing, it treats it as **where column is null** constraint - that's why you're getting such a weird query. Use **whereRaw()** instead:

```
->whereRaw('connections.firm_id = invites.firm_id')
```

Comment: Saved me some headaches.